# Show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+p)}=\frac{1}{p!p} $ for every positive integer $p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

I have to prove that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+p)}=\dfrac{1}{p!p}$$

How can I do that?

Comment: what is it? i or k?

Comment: Sorry, it is k=1 to infinity.

Comment: Are you sure that the result is not $\frac{1}{(p-1) p!}$ ?

Comment: Im sorry again, I forgot a k in the denominator, so probably your solution is right :D

Comment: Did you mean 'series'?

Comment: I think the result is 1/p!p. see my proposal below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{k(k\!+\!1)(k\!+\!2)\cdots (k\!+\!p)}=\frac{1}{p}\!\left(\frac{1}{k(k\!+\!1)\cdots (k\!+\!p\!-\!1)}-\frac{1}{(k\!+\!1)(k\!+\!2)\cdots (k\!+\!p)}\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+p)}=\\=\frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{1}{p!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots (n+p)}\right) \to \frac{1}{p!p}
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Similarly, 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+p)}=\\=\frac{1}{p-1}\left(\frac{1}{p!}--\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots (n+p)}\right) \to \frac{1}{p!(p-1)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

### Simpler answer: Telescope

for fixed $p\in\Bbb N$  If we let 
$u_n =\frac1{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p-1)}$

then,

$u_n -u_{n+1} = \frac1{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)}
=\frac p{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)}$

Hence By Telescoping sum we get, $$ u_1 = u_1-\lim_{n\to \infty}u_{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (u_n -u_{n+1}) = p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+p)}$$

But $u_1 = \frac1{1(1+1)\cdots(1+p-1)} = \frac{1}{p!}$

Hence $$ \color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+p)} = \frac{1}{p!p}}$$

Comment: Why a Down vote please?

Comment: I did not downvote but your answer is very similar to the first answer, which seems to be quite older then your answer. If the first answer was not correct you should have commented on that instead if giving a new answer.