# How to compute the limit of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)\ldots(n+m)}$, $m \in \mathbf{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, telescopic-series

For having some fun with infinite series, I am having a go at some of the exercises in `Problems in Mathematical Analysis` by Kaczor and Nowak. I would like to ask, if my approach is in the correct direction or if there's another clever way of algebraically manipulating this. Please don't post the solution - but rather a hint/tip.

Problem 3.1.4(a)

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+m)}, \quad m \in \mathbf{N}
> \end{align*}

**Solution.**

My approach would be to somehow, express this infinite sum as a telescopic series. Let's start with a simpler case $n=3$. We would like to determine coefficients $A,B,C,D$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}= \frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+1} + \frac{C}{n+2} + \frac{D}{n+3}$$

So,

\begin{align*}
1 = A(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) + Bn(n+2)(n+3) + Cn(n+1)(n+3) + Dn(n+1)(n+2)
\end{align*}

Substituting the values $n=0,-1,-2,-3$, we find that, $A=\frac{1}{6},B=-\frac{1}{2}, C=\frac{1}{2}, D=-\frac{1}{6}$. Thus,

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}= \frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{3}{n+1} + \frac{3}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3}\right)$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}= \frac{1}{4!}\left(\frac{1}{n} - {4 \choose 1} \frac{1}{n+1} + {4 \choose 2}\frac{1}{n+2} - {4 \choose 3}\frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{n+4}\right)$$

In general,

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\ldots(n+m)}= \frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{1}{n} - {m \choose 1} \frac{1}{n+1} + {m \choose 2}\frac{1}{n+2} - {m \choose 3}\frac{1}{n+3} + \ldots+ \frac{1}{n+m}\right)$$

(This should be proved rigorously using mathematical induction.)

But, if now look at the partial sum $s_n$ and write it for simplicity as -

\begin{align*}
s_n &= \frac{1}{m!} \left[1 - {m \choose 1} \frac{1}{2} + {m \choose 2}\frac{1}{3} - {m \choose 3 }\ \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + (-1)^m\frac{1}{1+m}\right]\\
&+ \frac{1}{m!} \left[\frac{1}{2} - {m \choose 1} \frac{1}{3} + {m \choose 2}\frac{1}{4} - {m \choose 3 }\ \frac{1}{5} + \ldots + (-1)^m\frac{1}{2+m}\right]\\
&+ \vdots \\
&+ \frac{1}{m!} \left[\frac{1}{n} - {m \choose 1} \frac{1}{n+1} + {m \choose 2}\frac{1}{n+2} - {m \choose 3 }\ \frac{1}{n+3} + \ldots + (-1)^m\frac{1}{n+m}\right]\\
\end{align*}

This doesn't really yield anything familiar, even if collect the terms for each fraction $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004004/show-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1kk1k2-cdots-kp-frac1p.